# select value in dynamic dropdown list in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, dropdown

I'm having a problem selecting certain value in a dynamic dropdown list. The scenario is when there is a newly added value on the DDL then my scripts will fail since the xpath position changes once there is new values.[this is the script in selecting the xpath][2]

Thanks in advance!

This is the html source [html source of the DDL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsgSh.png)

Comment: Add the html source in the question, together with the code you tried to accomplish the task - screenshots will simply not do. The main problem is your path references absolute positions, which as you said are dynamic.

Comment: Sorry but the source is not yet up, were currently in development. But what could be the command that will fix the said problem?

Comment: "but the source is not yet up, were" - if you can get a screenshot with a browser, you can get the html source. There's no command per se - it's a solution for the particular situation, with locators having attributes/text of the elements. And looking at the screenshot, this is probably not a normal html dropdown with `ul`/`ol` elements, but something with `div` or `span`, which makes the solution even more dependent on the html.

Comment: i've attached the html source for the DDL on my post. Thanks Todor!

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Does the XPath of the DDL change, or are the DDL items generated when you click the DDL and *those* are what change every time you open the DDL?

Comment: Yes the xpath of the DDL items changes upon adding new item/s

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation: http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html

You could try to select an item from the dropdown list by value or label with the keywords:

'Select From List By Label'

'Select From List By Value'